# Template binding of dependency property inside generic.Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a custom radio button control and defined a dependency property in it. In generic.Xaml, I put an ellipse and set Fill property to TemplateBinding SelectedColor. Here SelectColor is a dependency property and I assigned its value in mainpage where I use this control. But this fill property of ellipse is not working.

```
public sealed class CustomControl1 : RadioButton
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }
    public Color SelectedColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color), typeof(CustomControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));
}
```

and styled the radio button in generic.xaml as

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App20">

<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                <Grid BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresente" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"  Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <Ellipse Height="25" Width="25"  Fill="{TemplateBinding SelectedColor}" />
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Foreground="Black" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and created instance of this custom control in main page.xaml

```
 <local:CustomControl1 SelectedColor="Green" Content="qweerrrt" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Shape.Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill(v=vs.110).aspx) DP is not a Color it's a Brush. Your DP should be a Brush.

Or you could write:

```
<Ellipse Height="25" Width="25">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{TemplateBinding SelectedColor}"/>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```